# Regular Expression Regex in xml attrubute

Tags: regex, xml

I need to get text inbetween single quotes(') will be in blue color what i need to change in my xml BeginBlock attribute using Regular expression?

```
This is my code :

<lexem BeginBlock='\'[.*]\'' Color="Blue" />
```

This is not working for me. Any one can tell where i did the mistake.

Help me !

Comment: My xml file like this <lexem BeginBlock='\'[.*]\'' Color="Blue" />

Comment: No context, no examples, no efforts/code. I would suggest to use an XML parser

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regular expressions, but as Hamza said you would be better with a XML Parser

[^']\w+(?=')

(?>=').+(?=')

Answer (score 0):

Try `<lexem BeginBlock="'[.*]'" Color="Blue" />`.

Or even shorter `<lexem BeginBlock="'.*'" Color="Blue" />`.